# Facebook App in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, facebook-apps

Hi everybody i make a facebook app in asp.net and mvc . My problem i cant use to different model in index. I try tuple but not accepted and i have  tried to change MyAppUser model and again didnt accept from program.  How should i try  different model in same index ?

```
  public class MyAppUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("picture")] // This renames the property to picture.
    [FacebookFieldModifier("type(large)")] // This sets the picture size to large.
    public FacebookConnection<FacebookPicture> ProfilePicture { get; set; }

}
```

and other model

```
 public class NumberModel
{
    public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public int SecondNumber { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding your problem here, you need 2 models in your Index view? Obviously MVC only accepts one, so create a viewmodel and use the 2 different models in there.

Comment: i did that but return nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can have just one Index() but you have many choices how to bind the data:

**Two models**

```
    public ActionResult Index(MyAppUser appUser, NumberModel numberModel)
    {
        if (appUser != null)
        {
            // todo
        }
    }
```

**One shared viewmodel**

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public MyAppUser MyAppUser { get; set; }
        public NumberModel NumberModel { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.MyAppUser != null)
        {
            // todo
        }
    }
```

**Combination of both**

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public MyAppUser MyAppUser { get; set; }
        public NumberModel NumberModel { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "MyAppUser")]MyAppUser appUser, [Bind(Prefix = "NumberModel")]NumberModel numberModel)
    {
        if (appUser != null)
        {
            // todo
        }
    }
```

I think, in your case is the best solution to use shared ViewModel and check the objects inside ViewModel for NULL.